# fade content but show first jquery

Tags: jquery, show-hide, fade

I have a simple map with links and on click, the content fades in and replaces the other.

Problem: Every content is hidden on first visit, how I can tell jquery that the first content block "map_overview" has to been displayed, while the rest of the content is hidden until they are klicked by their related link.

Code HTML:

```
<div id="suburbanmap"> 

<div id="stmap">
<a class="stmaplink stmap-overview" id="show_overview">Overview</a>
<a class="stmaplink stmap-content1" id="show_content1">Link to content 1</a>
<a class="stmaplink stmap-content2" id="show_content2">Link to content 2</a>
<a class="stmaplink stmap-content3" id="show_content3">Link to content 3</a>
</div>   

<div id="mapcontent"> 

<div id="map_overview" class="stmc stmc-overview">
<h3>Overview</h3>
Example Text of the the overview introduction. This content is the first which will be shown and has to be displayed while the rest is hidden.
</div>     

<div id="map_content1" class="stmc stmc-content1">
<h3>Content 1</h3>
</div>

<div id="map_content2" class="stmc stmc-content2">
<h3>Content 2</h3>
</div>

<div id="map_content3" class="stmc stmc-content3">
<h3>Content 3</h3>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Code CSS:

```
#mapcontent .stmc { display: none; width: 550px; float: left; }
```

Code Jquery:

```
$("#stmap a").click(function(){
      var id =  $(this).attr('id');
      id = id.split('_');
       $("#mapcontent .stmc").fadeOut(500).hide(); 
      $("#mapcontent #map_"+id[1]).fadeIn(500).show();
      var maplinks = $("#stmap a");
    maplinks.click(function () {
        maplinks.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
   });
```

the jquery is founded on stackoverflow and modified. Maybe someone has a solution ?

Comment: after adding the click handler just call `$("#stmap a").first().triggerHandler('click')`

Answer (score 0):

Tell it to fire the click event when the document loads.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#map_overview').click();
});
```

Or just set the display to block for that specific div, either by setting an inline style or using jQuery:

```
<div id="map_overview" class="stmc stmc-overview" style="display:block">
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#map_overview').css('display', 'block');
});
```